# Powering Raspberry Pi and motors with same battery

Tags: raspberry-pi, l298, 18650

I'm building a Raspberry Pi (2 model B) robot with two l298n H-bridge modules to drive four motors, and am using the charger board module pictured below (lx-lbu2c - 2.4a output) to charge two 18650 cells in parallel. Using the USB out on the charger board powers the Raspberry Pi, but the motors aren't getting much power (I'm using one USB A port for the Pi and the other for the motors, but I think the 2.4 amps is shared between the two ports).

- Is it safe (and would it work) to connect additional wires directly to the battery box to drive the motors (using a step-up module to boost the voltage)?
- Would charging the batteries while they are connected to the l298n modules be a problem?

[image]

Comment: L298n is honestly a non-starter since the mid 1980s; its pretty obsolete with the high losses it incurs due to obsolete transistor technology, and due to that you not only lose a lot of motor power, you also have to deal with a lot of waste heat. Replace that with a MOSFET-based, slightly younger motor driver IC: you will not regret it. And: the fact that your motor driver "swallows" a lot of power is probably one of your problems here.

Comment: However, you haven't told us about the motors. Often, motors can draw very high current for short durations, and it would be a bad idea to drive them from USB at all, no matter through which board. Plus, aside from the photo, we know nothing about your charger, so we can't advise on what that can do, either :(

Comment: These are TT motors (https://www.adafruit.com/product/3777). I'll look into a MOSFET driver, but is it a problem to draw power directly to the batteries while they are hooked up to / being charged by the charger board?

Comment: As said, can't tell you, we have no data on your charger.

Comment: ah, and even adafruit recommends a MOSFET motor driver, the DRVsomehtingsomething!

Comment: @MarcusMüller it is lx-lbu2c - here is the one I have: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004691493942.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.62.1ed41802FKuzGr&gatewayAdapt=glo2vnm#nav-description

Comment: that product page's photo looks very different than the one you have here? Are you sure you have the same device? And: I can't find a datasheet on that page, do you have a link to one?

Comment: @MarcusMüller there are three variations on that page. I have the 5V 2.4A-B variant (choose the first option under "color") or expand the details section.

Comment: thanks, but still no datasheet! Impossible to know what that charger tolerates. Generally, you'd want a charger that is designed to power a system load while charging. And nothing here says that's the case for this *extremely* low cost device. So, I'd assume that's not the case.